# how to show the bidimensional elements of an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

i'm doing a game, and I want to show all the layers of my map, I have the two-dimensional array called capa, and each capa is in an unidimensional array called capas, this is the code:

```
self.capa = mainNode.childNodes[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].data.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "")
self.capa = decode(self.capa) # Decode the list

self.capa = convert(self.capa, self.width) # Convert in array bidimensional

self.capas.append(self.capa)
```

when i show each element of an array I do a for and I print in each step, but how do i do in this ocassion?thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always reiterate through the array to print the values. Or you might just print the entire array. In that case, I'd recommend using the pprint module, to pretty print the entire array after it is formed; the output is much more readable.